# What steps are done by XeLaTeX when compiling input files with PSTricks codes, jpeg, png, eps, pdf images?

Tags: xetex, ps2pdf, dvips, jpeg

I am confused why XeLaTeX can produce a pdf output from an input file that contains PSTricks codes, PNG, JPEG, PDF, EPS images. It is the first time I use XeLaTeX and I am really surprised that I can import images from many different format in the same input file.

Usually I use latex-dvips-ps2pdf to compile my input file that contains PSTricks codes and only EPS images. If I have PNG, JPEG and PDF images, I must convert them in advance to get the EPS version.

Unfortunately, XeLaTeX runs slower than latex-dvips-ps2pdf. I don't know why. Behind the scene, what steps are actually done by XeLaTeX when compiling input files with PSTricks codes, jpeg, png, eps, pdf images?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

JPEG, PNG and PDF are directly supported by PDF format, then they're supported by `xdvipdfmx` directly. `xetex` program reads the image files to determine the bounding boxes and produce a `.xdv` file, then `xdvipdfmx` program put the image data to PDF output file.

PDF format does not support PostScript stream, thus EPS files are converted to PDF format and then put into PDF output file. `xdvipdfmx` calls GhostScript to do the trick.

PSTricks pacakge also calls GhostScript to render the PostScript code. The code needed is in `xdvipdfmx.con`. Herbert may give more explanations.

Comment: Could it be possible to update the pdf(La)TeX engine so that it would handle PostScript and PStricks commands in a way similar to XeteX does?

Comment: @pluton: That's possible. In fact, new `epstopdf` package (which is automatically included now) and `auto-pst-pdf` of `PSTricks` does some of the tricks.

Comment: yes, but I was thinking of a more integrated solution where we do not have to load specific package and use external engines to do the work. Thanks

Comment: @pluton: Well, that's what `dvipdfmx` do. `dvipdfmx` also loads GhostScript to process PostScript code. You may ask LuaTeX developers to call the external programs automatically.

Answer (score 6):

XeTeX outputs an `xdv` file (extended DVI) which is piped to `xdvipdfmx` which understands Postscript specials and is capable to include EPS, PDF, PNG and JPEG files.

You can also use `latex+dvipdfmx` in order to include <strike>PSTricks files as well as</strike> EPS, PDF, PNG and JPEG files. This requires to pass **graphicx** <strike>and PSTtricks</strike> the `dvipdfm` option (`dvipdfmx` is an extended version of `dvipdfm`).

Note: it seems that "latex+dvipdfmx" is not able to include PSTtricks. :(

Comment: Is XeTeX identical to XeLaTeX?

Comment: @xport: XeLaTeX is just XeTeX with LaTeX format.

Comment: @egreg: XeLaTeX outputs pdf or xdv? I have tried it, it produces pdf.

Comment: XeTeX itself output a `.xdv` file, and automaticly call xdvipdfmx to produce PDF output.

Comment: @Leo: I see. I also noticed that  MGS.EXE is executed after xdvipdfmx.

Comment: @Jasper: I thought it could, seen that xdvipdfmx can.